# How do I iterate through table rows and cells in JavaScript and add the values?

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

This is my HTML table, on the table I have 3 rows and 3 columns, what I am trying to do is add the first two columns together and put the result in the third column. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
  .tg  { border-collapse:collapse; border-spacing:0; border-color:#bbb; }
  .tg td { font-family:Arial, sans-serif; font-size:14px; padding:10px 5px;border-
style:solid; border-width:0px; overflow:hidden; word-break:normal; border-
color:#bbb; color:#594F4F; background-color:#E0FFEB; }
  .tg th { font-family:Arial, sans-serif; font-size:14px; font-
weight:normal; padding:10px 5px; border-style:solid; border-
width:0px; overflow:hidden; word-break:normal; border-
color:#bbb; color:#493F3F; background-color:#9DE0AD; }
  .tg .tg-jf1j { font-weight:bold; font-size:20px; color:#ffccc9; text-
align:center; vertical-align:top; }
  .tg .tg-yw4l { vertical-align:top; }
</style>
```

HTML:

```
<table class="tg">
    <tr>
        <th class="tg-yw4l">1</th>
        <th class="tg-yw4l">1</th>
        <th id="a"></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="tg-yw4l">1</td>
        <td class="tg-yw4l">2</td>
        <td id="a"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="tg-yw4l">2</td>
        <td class="tg-yw4l">3</td>
        <td id="a"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Below here is where I try looping through my table and adding the first two columns together.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var table = document.getElementsByClassName("tg");

    for (var r = 0; r < 3; r++) {
        var sum1 = 0;

        for (var c = 0; c < 3; r++) {
            if (table[r][c].className == 'tg-yw41') {
                sum1 += isNaN(table[r][c].innerHTML) ? 0 : parseInt(table[r][c].innerHTML);
            }
        }

        document.getElementById('a').innerHTML = sum1;
    }
 </script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below code will add first and second `td/th` and show sum in third `td/th`.

*Note : You can further add error handling of Nan and other things.*

**Jquery Code :**

```
$('table.tg tr').each(function() {
    var third_var = parseInt($(this).find('th:first-child, td:first-child').html()) + parseInt($(this).find('th:nth-child(2), td:nth-child(2)').html());
    $(this).find('th:nth-child(3), td:nth-child(3)').html(third_var);
});
```

**Javascript Code : [Online Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/j0xuaLmo/)** As requested by @Alex_89

```
var table = document.getElementsByClassName("tg");
var t  = table[0];
for (var r = 0; r < t.rows.length; r++) {
    t.rows[r].cells[2].innerHTML = parseInt(t.rows[r].cells[0].innerHTML) + parseInt(t.rows[r].cells[1].innerHTML);
}
```

Comment: I can't try it right now, @Touheed, but I think yours is a good solution. Just remember he's not using JQuery. Maybe update your answer to pure JS. However, Josh, if you can, I thinks everyone here would strongly suggest you incorporate JQuery to your project/demo.

Comment: @Alex_89 : thanks. I didn't considered that. I'll play with JS and see if I can find solution in JS too.

Comment: @Alex_89 : updated answer, heartbreaking to see other answer get accepted ;P :D

Comment: It happens man, :D... However, I just tested your code with the demo you left in JSFiddle and it works perfectly. At least your answer gets an up vote from me.

Comment: BTW, @josh, it's ok to accept more than one answer if they're correct and solve your problem too.

Comment: @Alex_89 Thanks man :) there is some hope left in earth :P :D

Answer (score 0):

Solution for your question

```js
var table = document.getElementById("tg");
 for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) 
 {
  var sum1= 0;
  for (var j = 0, col; col = row.cells[j]; j++) 
  {
   sum1+=(col.textContent!='')?parseInt(col.textContent):0;   
  }
  var a='a'+(i+1).toString();
  document.getElementById(a).innerHTML = sum1;
  sum1=0;
   }
```

```css
.tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;border-color:#bbb;}
.tg td{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-
style:solid;border-width:0px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-
color:#bbb;color:#594F4F;background-color:#E0FFEB;}
.tg th{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-
weight:normal;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-
width:0px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-
color:#bbb;color:#493F3F;background-color:#9DE0AD;}
.tg .tg-jf1j{font-weight:bold;font-size:20px;color:#ffccc9;text-
align:center;vertical-align:top}
.tg .tg-yw4l{vertical-align:top}
```

```html
<table id="tg" class="tg">

 <tr>
 <th class="tg-yw4l">1</th>
<th class="tg-yw4l">1</th>
<th id="a1"></th>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class="tg-yw4l">1</td>
<td class="tg-yw4l">2</td>
<td id="a2"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class="tg-yw4l">2</td>
<td class="tg-yw4l">3</td>
<td id="a3"></td>
</tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

solution with plain js with th and td support

```js
window.onload = function(){
var table = document.getElementsByClassName("tg")[0];

var rows = table.getElementsByTagName('tr');

for(var i =0 ; i < rows.length;i++ )
{
    if(i == 0)
    {
          var cells = rows[i].getElementsByTagName('th');
          cells[2].innerHTML = parseInt(cells[0].innerHTML) + parseInt(cells[1].innerHTML); 
         continue;
    }
      var cells =  rows[i].getElementsByTagName('td');
      cells[2].innerHTML = parseInt(cells[0].innerHTML) + parseInt(cells[1].innerHTML);
    
}
}
```

```css
.tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;border-color:#bbb;}
.tg td{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-
style:solid;border-width:0px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-
color:#bbb;color:#594F4F;background-color:#E0FFEB;}
.tg th{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-
weight:normal;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-
width:0px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-
color:#bbb;color:#493F3F;background-color:#9DE0AD;}
.tg .tg-jf1j{font-weight:bold;font-size:20px;color:#ffccc9;text-
align:center;vertical-align:top}
.tg .tg-yw4l{vertical-align:top}
```

```html
<style type="text/css">

</style>


<table class="tg">

 <tr>
 <th class="tg-yw4l">1</th>
<th class="tg-yw4l">1</th>
<th id="a"></th>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class="tg-yw4l">1</td>
<td class="tg-yw4l">2</td>
<td id="a"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class="tg-yw4l">2</td>
<td class="tg-yw4l">3</td>
<td id="a"></td>
</tr>

</table>
```